# Set pop up help of a function for Intelligence support in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

As we all see in the intelligence support for Visual Studios, anything that is part of the code written by Microsoft has a details section which provide information on the functionality of a variable, event, function etc, as a pop up help. Where as the functions written by us only provide information on the expected variables to be passed. May someone please help me with finding out, how to write information for the details section for the user written code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're looking for [XML documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx). For example:

```
/// <summary>This method does something funky.</summary>
public void Foo()
{
}
```

Type /// just above your method declaration to get Visual Studio to create a skeleton for you. If you want to distribute the documentation along with a library, you'll need to turn on the XML generation in your project properties. You should generally name the XML file the same as the DLL, e.g. Acme.MyProject.dll would have documentation in Acme.MyProject.xml.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Great! I was looking for that too. Thx

Answer (score 1):

What your looking for is

```
///<summary>
```

right before your declaration of your method try entering "///" it should start the process of using the XML comments.  It will automatically show all of the parameters of the method as well as the return...

You can get more info at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Use the XML Documentation Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04awywx.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. Really appreciate the help.